# how do you use a method with a return statement in an interface?

Tags: java, methods, return, boolean

I am confused as to how to include a return statement in a method in an interface?

This is my question-
Develop an Interface Usable to the following specifications:

It has a public method boolean isUsed() (). The method has no argument and returns, true if the object is used and false otherwise.

How do you include the return statement when in an interface, you cannot have a method body?

Comment: Questions asking for homework [help](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it.

Answer (score 1):

Interfaces in Java 8 can have a default implementation which can be overridden by the implementing class:

```
public interface Usable {
    default boolean isUsed() {
        return true;
    }
}
```

However, you should allow the implementing class to handle the logic by returning true or false

Comment: and how exactly is that done? could u please maybe show it?

Comment: By using the implements keyword, the logic is up to the implementing class and since the method is a default method, it _can_ override it if it wishes or go with the default implementation

Answer (score 0):

Interface by design only supply the method signature. its up to the implementing class to implement the method logic.

In your case build your interface with only the method signature (which return a boolean) and in the implementing class, insert the business logic